# Як правильно перекласти "retrieve" чи "извлекать" (інформацію/записи/etc)

Tags: переклад, from-english, from-russian

Шукаю переклад поняттю *витягування* / *видобування* / *отримування* інформації або записів звідкись, що звичайно представлені англійским дієсловом **retrieve** або російським **извлекать**.

Приклад зі словника:

> to find and get (information) from a computer/disk/system
>
> - You can quickly retrieve data/information.
> - The files were retrieved from the computer.
> - He was able to retrieve the document.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76006/discussion-on-question-by-gavenkoa----retrieve--).

Answer (score 10):

В англійській Вікіпедії є стаття [data retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_retrieval), де вказано "Not to be confused with [Information retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval)", оскільки це різні терміни і тому переклад буде залежати від контексту.

*Data retrieval* - це отримання даних, що знаходяться в базі даних. Отримання даних відбувається за допомогою *запитів* (*queries*), тому в цьому випадку коректно вживати фразу ***запит даних***.

*Information retrieval* означає пошук релевантних нашому запиту інформаційних ресурсів. Тому найкоректнішим перекладом є ***інформаційний пошук*** (пошук інформації в пошукових системах на кшталт Google або Bing).

Є ще термін *data mining* (часто вживається як синонім *data retrieval* та *knowledge discovery*) в значенні *"виявлення прихованих закономірностей або взаємозв'язків між змінними у великих масивах необроблених даних"*, то українська Вікіпедія [пропонує](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85) використовувати варіанти ***отримання даних*** або ***добування даних***. Проте ці переклади не відображають коректно суть терміну *data mining*. Більш точним перекладом є ***пошук знань*** або *знаходження знань [в великих масивах інформації]*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55579/discussion-on-answer-by-sashaeve----retrieve--).

Answer (score 8):

Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко «Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики» (2010):

> [retrieve](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=retrieve&dicts=2) [rɪ'tri:v] =
>   *1.* віднахо́дити/віднайти́  *2.* шука́ти *3.* віднови́ти; ви́правити
>   *4.* видобува́ти/ви́добути *(інформацію)*
>
> [retrieval](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=retrieval&dicts=2) [rɪ'tri:vl] = по́шук; вибира́ння; відна́йдення, видобува́ння
>     • data ~ = по́шук да́них; добира́ння (відна́йдення) да́них
>     • information ~ = по́шук інформа́ції, інформаці́йний по́шук

Translations in Localized Microsoft Products:

> [retrieve data](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=retrieve+data&langID=uk-ua) = **отримати** дані
>   [retrieve information](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=retrieve+information&langID=uk-ua) = **отримати** інформацію, відомості
>   [data retrieval](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=data+retrieval&langID=uk-ua) = **отримання**, **видобування**, **витягнення** даних
>   [information retrieval](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=information+retrieval&langID=uk-ua) = інформаційний **пошук**, **отримання** відомостей

[KDE Localizations](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk):

> to retrieve [information/data/etc] = **отримати/отримувати**
>   [information/data/etc] retrieval = **отримання**

Ukrainian Translations for Chromium Browser:

> [retrieve](//translations.launchpad.net/chromium-browser/translations/+pots/chromium-browser/uk/+translate?batch=50&search=retrieve) = **отримати/отримувати**

Drupal Translations:

> [retrieve](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=retrieve&status=2&limit=50) + [retrieval](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?search=retrieval&status=2&limit=50):
>     • **отриманий/отримати/отримувати/отримання** — ×20
>     • **одержати/одержання** — ×4
>     • **вибір**, **видобутий**, **витягати**, **відокремлювати**, **пошук** — по 1 разу

Висновки:

- отрим(ув)ати, отрим<s>ув</s>ання — безперечний практичний лідер;
- видобу(ва)ти, видобування (видобуток?) — є в словниках, трішки вживає Microsoft;
- одерж(ув)ати, одерж<s>ув</s>ання — трішки вживає Drupal;
- витяг(<s>ув</s>а)ти, витяг<s>ув</s>ання/витягнення — трішки вживає Microsoft;
- діста(ва)ти, діставання — ніхто не вживає (а мені подобається);
- відбирати/відібрати, відбір — ніхто не вживає (а мені подобається);
- добирати/дібрати, добирання — іменник у словнику;
- віднаходити/віднайти, віднаходження/віднайдення — є в словниках.

Answer (score 7):

*retrieve* використовується в англійській в дуже широкому сенсі для отримання даних, тому в залежності від нюансів контексту перекладами можуть бути такі слова як отримувати/одержувати, зчитувати, витягати, видобувати, діставати, виймати, запитувати.

Одночасно російське *извлекать*, яке автор вважає аналогом *retrieve*, теж не є його універсальним відповідником і не є точним словом для перекладу всіх трьох речень англійською, що наведені як приклади.

Що ж стосується російського *извлекать* в контексті баз даних, то в навчальних матеріалах і документації я найчастіше зустрічав *видобування* і ***витягання***. Пошук в Гугл [першого](https://google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%85%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VEC3WODACYGm8we24YXwAw#safe=off&channel=fs&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%22&*) і [другого](https://www.google.com/search?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VEC3WODACYGm8we24YXwAw&gws_rd=cr#safe=off&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%22&*) показує, що обидва словосполучення є вживаними саме в такому сенсі.

В ІТ-слензі (як рос. так і укр.) для операції пошуку і отримання даних часто використовується слово *витягати*, але на відміну від російської, саме в українській *витягати* має набагато менш колоквіальну конотацію, насамперед через те, що це і інші однокореневі слова вже широко вживаються зі схожими за змістом значеннями, наприклад *витяг з правил*.

Ще одним аргументом на користь *вигягати* є значення №6 у [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vytjaghaty), яке за змістом є близьким до операції пошуку і отримання даних з БД: *Знаходячи, вибираючи, використовувати, виписувати з тексту.*